# Overwriting array in dafny

Tags: dafny

I'm trying to overwrite an array inside a method. The compiler is giving me the error "Error: LHS of assignment must denote a mutable variable".

```
    method invalidSort(a : array<int>)
    modifies a;
    requires a != null;
    ensures sorted(a[..]);
    {
       a := new int[0];
    }
```

Am I staring myself blind and missing something or why does Dafny not allow this?

Answer (score 2):

In Dafny, method parameters cannot be assigned to. You can use a local variable if you need to update the value internally.

For example,

```
var a' := new int[0];
```

If you want this new array to be available to the caller, you'll also need to return it.

```
return a';
```

All that said, if you're trying to write an in-place sorting method, then you don't need to do any of this. Just modify `a` in place.

```
a[0] := 0;
// ...
```

Comment: I've tried but then it complains about that the post-condition doesn't hold. I don't know if I need some loop invariant but none of what I've tried works.

Comment: @mackmut Can you ask another question about the postcondition that doesn't hold?